# Data are not sent between Arduino uno and NodeMcu esp8266 at all time

Tags: firebase, arduino, iot, nodemcu

I am sending data from Arduino UNO R3 to nodeMcu esp8266. In that case sometime data are send properly but at sometime data are are not send by arduino or not get by nodemcu esp8266.Also tx light not blinks after i upload the code to the Arduiono.

```
enter code here
```

Code Uploaded to Arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
SoftwareSerial s(10,11);
SoftwareSerial h(10,11);
int i=0;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
s.begin(9600);
Serial.begin(9600);
}
int f1=0;
int f2=0;
String st="sy";
void loop() {
  f1=f1+1;
  f2=f2+2;
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
StaticJsonBuffer <1000> bf;
StaticJsonBuffer <1000> rec;
 JsonObject& root=bf.createObject();
 JsonObject& receives=rec.parseObject(h);
 if (receives==JsonObject::invalid())
 {
  Serial.println("no data from nodemcu");
  root["data3"]="no data from nide";
  }
  else
  {
    root["data3"] = receives["data3"];
    //st = (const char*)receive["data3"];
  }
root["data1"]=f1;
root["data2"]=f2;
//root["data3"]=st;
if(s.available()>0)
{
  root.printTo(s);
  Serial.println("send");
}
else
{
  Serial.println("NOt Available");}
//i=i+1;
//s.write(i);
delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code thera are two reasons I can spot on the first look:
1 Never use delay in server client applications. Delay stops proccessing and inhibts communication. For more details how to avoid look at the blinkwithoutdelay built in Example in the Arduino IDE.
2. You use ArduinoJSON: This lib is absolute overkill for 99% of the applications it  is used for. Don't get me wrong - the lib offers fantastic features, but if not needed this can be regarded as bloat-ware.
I wrote my own simple JSON coding/decoding (~250 lines of code) for a performant application using an Arduino as "Signal generator" and the ESP8266/ESP32 as a webserver. Communication between Arduino and ESPis time critical and so far it works over a year without problems,